# createBottomTabNavigator: undefined is not a function

Tags: react-native

I can't understand why I have the error defined in the title.
Any help will be greatly aprreciated as I'am going insane !

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './navigation/Navigation';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import Store from './store/configureStore';
import {persistStore} from 'redux-persist';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let persistor = persistStore(Store);
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <Navigation />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

My navigation page:
/navigation/Navigation.js
**Error is raised at line const BookFlightTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import Search from '../components/Search'; // no {} for script that use export ...
import BoardingPass from '../components/BoardingPass'; // no {} for script that use export ...
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {
  //createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation-stack';

const SearchStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Search: {
    screen: Search,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Rechercher',
    },
  },
});

const BoardingPassStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  BoardingPass: {
    screen: BoardingPass,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Votre réservation',
    },
  },
});

const BookFlightTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    // Search: {
    //   screen: Search, // Define a stack navigator when have further screens .... else a simple scrren is good
    //   navigationOptions: {
    //     tabBarLabel: 'Search',
    //   },
    // },
    Search: {
      screen: SearchStackNavigator, // Define a stack navigator when have further screens .... else a simple scrren is good
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: () => {
          return (
            <Image
              source={require('../images/ic_search_unselected.png')}
              style={styles.icon}
            />
          );
        },
      },
    },
    BoardingPass: {
      screen: BoardingPassStackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: () => {
          return (
            <Image
              source={require('../images/ic_boarding-pass-unselected.png')}
              style={styles.icon}
            />
          );
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeBackgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
      inactiveBackgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      showLabel: false,
      showIcon: true,
    },
  },
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(BookFlightTabNavigator);
```

components/Search.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';

class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <Text style={styles.headline}>Template Component </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  headline: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

export default Search;
```

components/BoardingPass.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';

class BoardingPassextends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <Text style={styles.headline}>Template Component </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  headline: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

export default BoardingPass;
```

package.son

```
{
  "name": "BookFlightApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^4.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "react": "16.13.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.2.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "5.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, activeTintColor, focused }) =>
                //  
                // 
                focused ?
                    ()
                    : (
                    )
        }
    },
})

try using this way,

Comment: To add & clarify the solution. Import createBottomTabNavigator from 'react-navigation-tabs' instead of 'react-navigation-stack'

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Jan 2024**

Use `import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";` instead as `react-navigation-tabs` is currently deprecated.

According to official docs,

> This package is no longer supported. Please use @react-navigation/bottom-tabs instead. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/ for usage guide